# Geolocation supported but not working

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to use the geolocation provided by the browser.

This is my code

```
console.log("Before Geolocation");

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("Geolocation Supported");
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                console.log("Within function");
                geoloc = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
                console.log(geoloc);                    
                }, 
            function(){ 
                console.log("error");
            },
            {
                timeout: 10000
            }
            );

        }
        else {
            console.log("geolocation not supported");
        }


        if (geoloc != '') {
            addition = geoloc;

        }

        else {

        addition = "DEFAULT LOCATION"; 

        }

        console.log(addition);
```

My problem is, when im running the code, the console output on chrome says:

```
Before Geolocation
Geolocation Supported
DEFAULT LOCATION
```

It seems like that the call:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
```

does not seem to be executed, as neither the success nor the failure function is doing something. (Which could be checked in the console)

What could be the reasons for the function not firing but geolocation being supported?

Comment: What is your testing environment? Are you testing locally?

Comment: no on a live server

Comment: Is it SSL (https)? Chrome will not allow accessing geolocation API on non-SSL websites.

Comment: thanks for that information, i didnt know that. However the website is on https://

Answer (score 2):

The function is called, but it's asynchronous. That's why you have to supply a callback function.

```js
var addition = "DEFAULT LOCATION";
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  console.log('geolocation supported');
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
} else {
  console.log("geolocation not supported");
  console.log(addition);
}

function success(position) {
  addition = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(addition);

  // I worked! Party on...
}

function error(err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, However i tried your approach and it didnt work :|

Comment: In what way do you feel that it is failing? I can click the "Run code snippet" button and see it work.

Comment: it doesnt output anything in the success function, it is the same result as above

Comment: Here's the exact same code on JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/b3ccLqn6/ Works like a champ.

Comment: okay that might be, if you copy my code in there it will be working too!

Comment: Well, not really. You test geoloc outside of the callback so it will always be equal to empty string.

Comment: actually yeah, the callback function is just defined in the function itself. Take a look at the mozilla guidelines: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

they do it like i did

Comment: Ok, I'm about done trying to explain this but, one last time, you have code OUTSIDE the callback function. This is code that will be run immediately after you call getCurrentPosition. getCurrentPosition takes a while to get a result. BEFORE you get this result back, you test the geoloc variable. This code will always fail because you aren't waiting for the result to get back. You have to place your test INSIDE the callback.

Comment: okay i understand that, but then the code within the success function should fire at some point. there is a console.log in there too. so even if it takes a while it at one point would send an entry to the console. right?